# How to make a crochet plush

Tags: texturing, sculpting

How can I achieve a realistic knitted texture for a crochet plush in Blender, ensuring it is suitable for 3D printing, considering that sculpting mode is challenging for this purpose?

Comment: Here's a pattern but 3D printing this may be challenging 
https://youtu.be/P3aNRRswE5Q?feature=shared  also 
https://youtu.be/gY-_CsSl1VI?feature=shared also https://youtu.be/QDB1wmQIsqE?feature=shared

Comment: I’ve tried all this methods! But for my case I want a physical texture that can be 3d printed!

Comment: Since you tried those methods. It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file of what you have to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  After that you can use the 3D Print Toolbox to check and export the mesh as an STL to test with.  https://youtu.be/0rgrLWFUjlk?feature=shared